# Voltage regulator or reference for a Wheatstone bridge excitation voltage?

Tags: voltage, precision

I will have a circuit which will be amplifying a Wheatstone-bridge(strain gage) signals by an instrumentation amplifier.
I read that the noise of a Wheatstone-bridge(strain gage) has very much to do with its excitation voltage.

So the question is I was planning to use a voltage regulator for the whole circuit.
But should I use a voltage reference for stability and less noise instead for the section which is used for the excitation voltage of the bridge? If I use voltage reference for the whole circuit I'm afraid current might be an issue. So anyone has experience with this?

Comment: How many active gauges in the bridge? What is their nominal resistance? What voltage regulator were you planning on using? What are you going to do with the output from the  InAmp? What power rails do you nominally have. What bandwidth are you considering? Please put this information in your question.

Comment: All four are active(full) 350Ω type with +/-5V supply. I will use bipolar supply for in-amp rails. I didnt chose any regulator yet. But for the in-amp positive supply rail I was planning to use an ordinary 5V voltage regulator and for the negative rail I was planning to use LTC1046 voltage converter to obtain -5V from the voltage regulator. For the straingage I was planning to use the same 5V regulator's output but my concern is the precision  affect on strain gage.

Comment: It would be great to see an example circuit for these powering parts. But the ones I saw so far in net doesnt not mention the supply and excitation or voltage regulator/reference parts in schematics.